# Element refusing to fade out or in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that is refusing to fade out or in (other elements work). When I run the jquery fadeOut() in the console it instantly dissapears from the screen??

Here is the html for the element:

```
<div class="span12">
    <h1 id="pagetitle" class="sitetitle lighttextbackground">
        <a href="asdsf.html">Alexandre</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#pagetitle").fadeOut(1250);
```

The whole site with css / js files etc can be seen here.

http://staging.alexandredairy.com/

I've debugged, cut and pasted the code in jsfiddle and I can't find the culprit so any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

---

### My Apologies. I have pushed code so you can see now

Comment: I don't see any id or fadeout action on your scripts .... when it fades out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the site you linked, your h1 doesn't have the pagetitle id.

```
$('.sitetitle').fadeOut(1250); // should work with current markup
```

**UPDATE**
I can see whats wrong now. You have both fadeOut() in the jQuery, and -webkit-trasistion ease-out in the css. If you remove the transition you'll get the jQuery to work. Tbh, I don't really know why they are blocking each other.

Comment: DOH!! I haven't uploaded it to server. On my dev box it is there.

Comment: Your update had the answer. So...was that just intellectual knowledge and you knew..or suspected...what to look for or is there some debugging method that tipped you off?

Comment: I have previously had somewhat similar problems myself. So just checked the css if you got any transitions/animations there and thought it might work to just turn them off.