# How to set the font color between black and white, depending on the color of the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a array(dynamic values) with hex colors and I want put the font color black for the light backgrounds and color White for the dark backgrounds

```
        /* array for example */
        var colorHexCode = ["#ECECEC", "#FFF", "#F4F2ED"];
        for (var i = 0; i < colorHexCode.length; i++) {
            var ColorLayerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            ColorLayerDiv.style.height = "10px";
            ColorLayerDiv.style.backgroundColor = colorHexCode[i];
            $('#Layers').append(ColorLayerDiv);
        }
```

I want set the font color automatic like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do this using js or query? if yes can you show me an example

Comment: This may help you [Given a RGB color x, how to find the most contrasting color y?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/38542)

Comment: This question might be exactly what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867545/change-text-color-based-on-brightness-of-the-covered-background-area

Cyang points to this article
https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast

Comment: [JS function for accessible color contrast](http://codepen.io/davidhalford/pen/ywEva)

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. I think he has a predefined set of colors which he wants to hardcode into his application. He nowhere mentions 'detect' or whatever. The other solutions are most probably way more complex than what he needs. @HudsonPH: I put the code I wanted to post as answer on github, check https://gist.github.com/mdix/96d8743fe0ee1a9abe8d7843009d92c0.

Comment: @MarcDix he said automatic.

Comment: @jcubic Lets wait for his answer...

Comment: jcubic and MarcDix thanks :D , @Rayon I dont want a PHP solution read the thing for complete before do this

Comment: @MarcDix I will use the solution of jcubic, need to be dynamic :P

Comment: @jcubic You were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

this piece of code, source: http://codepen.io/davidhalford/pen/ywEva ;

```
threshold = 130; /* about half of 256. Lower threshold equals more dark text on dark background  */

            hRed = hexToR(hex);
            hGreen = hexToG(hex);
            hBlue = hexToB(hex);


            function hexToR(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(0,2),16)}
            function hexToG(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(2,4),16)}
            function hexToB(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(4,6),16)}
            function cutHex(h) {return (h.charAt(0)=="#") ? h.substring(1,7):h}

            cBrightness = ((hRed * 299) + (hGreen * 587) + (hBlue * 114)) / 1000;
              if (cBrightness > threshold){return "#000000";} else { return "#ffffff";} 
          }
```

thanks @jcubic

Answer (score 0):

Here you find if your color i dark or light:

```
  (function ($) {

        $.fn.lightOrDark = function () {

        var r, b, g, hsp
          , a = this.css('background-color');

        if (a.match(/^rgb/)) {
            a = a.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/);
            r = a[1];
            g = a[2];
            b = a[3];
        } else {
            a = +("0x" + a.slice(1).replace( // thanks to jed : http://gist.github.com/983661
                a.length < 5 && /./g, '$&$&'
              )
            );
            r = a >> 16;
            b = a >> 8 & 255;
            g = a & 255;
        }
        hsp = Math.sqrt( // HSP equation from http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html
          0.299 * (r * r) +
          0.587 * (g * g) +
          0.114 * (b * b)
        );
        if (hsp > 127.5) {
            alert('light');
        } else {
            alert('dark');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the colors and calculate the brightness.

```
var colorHexCode = ["#ECECEC", "#FFF", "#F4F2ED","#777", "#FF0", '#00F'];
        for (var i = 0; i < colorHexCode.length; i++) {
            var ColorLayerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            ColorLayerDiv.style.height = "20px";
            ColorLayerDiv.style.backgroundColor = colorHexCode[i];

            //text color
            var c = colorHexCode[i];
            var brightness = 0;
            for(var j = 1; j< c.length; ++j){
                    var rgb = c[j];
                if(c.length==4)            
                    rgb += rgb;
                else {
                    j+=1;
                  rgb += c[j];
                }  
                var b = parseInt(rgb, 16);
                brightness += b;
            }
            ColorLayerDiv.innerText = c;
            ColorLayerDiv.style.color = brightness >= (255*3/2) ? 'black' : 'white';

            $('#Layers').append(ColorLayerDiv);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i forget to write need to be dynamic the values